# Find the highest N values of an array in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find the top N values in an array. So far I was able to find the highest one, but not to iterate and find the other N-1 values:

```
ar=(10 30 44 44 69 12 11)
max=${ar[0]}
for n in "${ar[@]}" ; do
    ((n > max)) && max=$n
done
echo $max
```

I think I cannot sort the array since I need to print the n higher values (e.g. 4) and the corresponding index (original position in the array).

Example of output from my array "ar":

value: 69, index: 4

value: 44, index: 3

value: 44, index: 2

value: 30, index: 1

Comment: sort and take the last n elements

Comment: What elements to do you want to get as output for the given input?

Comment: e.g `printf "%s\n" ${arr[@]} | sort -r | head -n "$n"` (where `$n` holds the top number of elements you are concerned with) Add ` | uniq` after `sort -r` to eliminate duplicates (or if your `sort` supports `-u`, just `sort -ru`)

Comment: You should add `-n` for a numeric sort as well.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell something important in the description. I need to print for example the 4 higher values and their corresponding index (position in the array). I will re-write the descrition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your array,

```
ar=(10 30 44 44 69 12 11)
```

and you want the top 3 largest values, then you need to sort your array in reverse and pick-off the first 3 values.

However, you just can't sort the result of `${ar[@]}` because that will list all values in a single line, and `sort` sorts lines. So you use the `printf` trick to turn your row of values into a single value per-line, e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]}
```

(**note:** `${ar[@]}` is *intentionally* unquoted)

Then to sort and pick off the top `3`, you could do:

```
$ printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]} | sort -rn | head -3)
69
44
44
```

if you want only uninque values, pipe the sorted results to `uniq` or if your `sort` supports the `-u` (unique) option, just add a `-u`), e.g.

```
$ printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]} | sort -rnu | head -3)
69
44
30
```

If you want to capture the top 3 in a new array, you can simply place the command in a *command substitution*, e.g.

```
$ newar=( $(printf "%s\n" ${ar[@]} | sort -rnu | head -3) )
```

**Mapping Original Index to Sort**

In follow-on to your comments, the easiest way to map the original index to the top-n sorted values would be to output the original array with indexes, then sort using the `-k KEYDEF` to on the value field (field 2) and then output the original index along with the sorted value:

```
#!/bin/bash

ar=(10 30 44 44 69 12 11)

{
for ((i = 0; i < ${#ar[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "%d %d\n" "$i" "${ar[i]}"
done
} | sort -rn -k2 | head -n 3
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash asort2.sh
4 69
3 44
2 44
```

or adding `-u` to remove duplicates:

```
$ bash asort2.sh
4 69
2 44
1 30
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I think I cannot sort the array since I need to print also the original index of those values (I added this info on the description, sorry). Do you think I can use your solution adding this constraint?

Comment: That doesn't change the original at all, it just sorts in a pipeline.

Comment: great!!! How can I print the corresponding (original) index in the printf command?

Comment: Oh, now you want to make it tough `:)` Since you still have the original array, you can simply loop `for ((i = 0; i < ${#ar[@]}; i++)); do [ "${newar[i]}" -eq "${ar[i]}" ] && echo "ar[$i] = ${ar[i]}"; done`

Comment: in this case, if I have two time the same value, the index is correct? It's not printing the same index for both?

Comment: You do have 2 of the same values, you have 2 `44`, so the different indexes are correct. If you want to get rid of that, then use `| uniq` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: This deserves a `++`, well written and explained!

Comment: @Inian That was one of those fun ones, the "brain teasers", where you have to sit back and think -- "now how would I do that??" Thanks for the accolades `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in a script:

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted_ar=($(sort -r <<<"${ar[*]}"))  # sort ar

n=4                                             # top count
for (( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ))
do 
  echo "${sorted_ar[i]}"
done

unset IFS
```